# Being able to access local storage image in another function

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm trying to create an app in which I have local storage entries with some information under which an image. I have a function that handles filreading for the image and a function that creates my entries when my form is submitted. Now I need to pass the image to the function that creates the entry when my form is submitted. How can I do this?

Function for file handling:

```
$('#image').on('change', handleFileSelect);

function handleFileSelect(e) {
    var photos = e.target.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < photos.length; i++) {
        var photo = photos[i];
        if (!photo.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
        }
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var img = e.target.result;
            // I want my image to be in the json_entry I create in submitForm();
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(photo);
    }
}
```

Function when form is submitted and where the entry is created:

```
function submitForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Create new JSON entry
    var json_entry = {'title': $("#title").val(),
                        'image': // I want my image to be in here,
                        'content': $("#story").val(),
                        'location': $("#locatie").val(),
                        'location_lat': $("#locatie_lat").val(),
                        'location_lon': $("#locatie_lon").val(),
                        'date': getCurrentDate(),
                        'key': Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000)};

    //Put the entry in localstorage
    localStorage.setItem(Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000), JSON.stringify(json_entry));

    //Add the entry to the overview
    $('#overview').append('<article class="diary_item" rel="'+json_entry.key+'"><h2>'+json_entry.title+'</h2><div style="position:relative;"><img class="entry_img" src="'+json_entry.image+'"><div class="location"><img src="gfx/location.svg">&nbsp;&nbsp;'+json_entry.location+'</div><img class="delete" src="gfx/close.svg" /></div><p>'+json_entry.content+'<span class="time">Added on:&nbsp;'+json_entry.date+'</span></p></article>');

}
```

I hope my question is clear and that someone can help me out. I really can't seem to get this thing working :(

Answer (score 0):

You've already decided that you'll be passing the image around and storing as a data uri string.

As I understand it, the problem is how to get that string to the other function. Well there's a really simple way to do that. Just store it in a global variable.